# #NAME Error For First Condition in "IF" Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've mentioned two conditions in "IF" formula in excel. Please see below formula;

```
=IF(AND(E2="India",I2<=TODAY()-3),”India”, IF(AND(E2="Sri Lanka",I2<=TODAY()-7),"Sri Lanka",))
```

It gives me an "#NAME?" error for first condition i.e. India & not showing actual result. Any Idea how to fix this & also get result with first condition too?

Comment: Your formula looks fine. Show data you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below formula worked perfect for me:

```
=IF(OR(AND(G2="India",I2<=TODAY()-3),AND(G2="Sri Lanka",I2<=TODAY()-7)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND(E2="India",I2<=TODAY()-3),"India",IF(AND(E2="Sri Lanka",I2<=TODAY()-7),"Sri Lanka",))
```

I guess the error may be caused by full-width quotes.   “ <> "

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using right double quotation marks instead of double quotation marks at the second use of the word India:

Your statement:

```
=IF(AND(E2="India",I2<=TODAY()-3),”India”, IF(AND(E2="Sri Lanka",I2<=TODAY()-7),"Sri Lanka",))
```

`”India”` using RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (incorrect)
`"India"` using DOUBLE QUOTATION (correct)

The correct statement is:

```
=IF(AND(E2="India",I2<=TODAY()-3),"India", IF(AND(E2="Sri Lanka",I2<=TODAY()-7),"Sri Lanka",))
```